# How do includes affect execution time in c++?

Tags: c++, csv, header, runtime

I was hoping to get some sort of clarification regarding the run time of my MSVS2015 community solution.

I've basically made quite a simple application that uses libcurl to get historical data from a CSV file from yahoo finance. The data is from 2010 to 2016, dumped into a csv file in the solution's folder.

The reason I'm raising this question is because since I changed the solution from just using a single .cpp executing everything to making new .cpp files to basically make the code more maintainable the run time went from >1 second to about 3 seconds. 
This is my first time working with multiple .cpp and .h files, so I have very limited experience with how including them could affect the run-time.

To iterate on the issue; it is actually working fine - I just wish to understand how the run time can be so much longer when making such easy changes.

Here is the code:

historical.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "historical.h"


using namespace std;

static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}


historical::historical(string symbol) {
    _mQueryString = "http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" + symbol + "&a=00&b=01&c=2010&d=01&e=01&f=2016&d=m&ignore=.csv"; // setup the query by adding the string param. (2010-2016).

    CURL *curl; // initialize cURL
    CURLcode res; // setup a response

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, _mQueryString);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &_mHistorical);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);


        string* pBuffer = &_mHistorical;
    }
}

string* historical::getHistorical() {
    return &_mHistorical;
}
historical::~historical() {
    cout << "The object is deleted";
}
```

historical.h

```
#pragma once

//======================
//include guard
#ifndef  __HISTORICAL_H_INCLUDED__
#define __HISTORICAL_H_INCLUDED__

//======================
// forward declared dependencies

//======================
// included dependencies::
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <curl/curl.h> 
#include <string>

//======================
// historical::

using namespace std;
class historical {
public:
    historical(string symbol);
    string* getHistorical();
    ~historical();
private:
    string _mHistorical;
    string _mQueryString;
};


#endif
```

geostocks.cpp (including main())

```
// geostocks.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <curl/curl.h> 
#include <string>
#include "historical.h"
using namespace std;

void writer(string* pInput);

static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}



int main(void)
{
    historical his("AAPL");
    string output;

    output = *his.getHistorical();
    writer(&output);

    return 0;
}

void writer(string* pInput) {
    ofstream mf("test.csv");
    if (mf.is_open()) {
        mf << *pInput;
        mf.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Your application timing seems really dependent of the timing of an http requests, that is not the most predictable for timing.

Comment: You're essentially measuring how long it takes to download the data (and for the server to prepare it), and variations of several seconds can be expected.

Comment: See, I understand that there might be variations on how long time it could take for the server to handle and prepare the data from a http request. However, doesn't it seem somewhat unlikely that the request (two identical requests) take different length of execution? I've re-run both solutions, and it the 'divided' solution takes 3-4 seconds, whereas the undivided takes less than 1 second to execute.

Comment: _"doesn't it seem somewhat unlikely that the request (two identical requests) take different length of execution?"_ No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in any way at all.

Your observations are *far* more likely to be due to the network HTTP request, wouldn't you say?

Comment: That would be my thoughts exactly. However, the request, response and writing does take 3-5 seconds longer when I 'divided' the original .cpp file to make it more manageable...

Comment: @geostocker: No, that is a co-incidence.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be a coincidence. Just ran it once more, with a ctime include.
Without being 'divided' it took less than one second. WIth it being 'divided' it took between 4-5 seconds.

Comment: @geostocker: Ok then you know best.

Comment: I clearly don't know best, or I wouldn't have raised this question. But surely you must understand my genuine confusion? I have done programming for quite a time, but am new to c/c++. But it does seem quite strange that the solutions have such drastic changes in execution time... :/

Comment: @geostocker: They don't! They can't. Something else must be causing it and you are jumping to conclusions when interpreting your results :P Perhaps you made a fundamental change to your program at the same time as splitting up the code?

Comment: That's so strange. The only difference is that I created a .cpp that holds a class (historical) which handles the same cURL http request as the undivided does, with the change that as historical is constructed it uses its param (symbol) to create the query-string.
Then the main class constructs an instance of historical (which constructs and executes the request). Then the main gets the string which the historical data is stored in. And finally it invokes historical's destructor... :/

Comment: @geostocker: That sounds a lot different than just lexically splitting up some files. How did you conclude that the `#include`s were at fault?

Comment: Well, yeah. It is definately different from the undivided, but I honestly didn't think it would make such a huge impact on execution time.

I thought it might have been a problem with circular includes or something of the sort rather than initilizing an instance of a class and then using its getter to getting the pointer to a string that holds the same value as the undivided solution.

Comment: @geostocker: Code layout is 100% unrelated to runtime execution speed. Your code doesn't even _exist_ at runtime!

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing this up for me. I've already marked your answer as the correct one as you have taken quite a lot of time off your hands to explain it to me. Would you mind telling me, in short, how I could possibly optimize the code? Seeing as the execution is longer now, what can I do to make it quicker? Especially since I'll have to use historical.cpp to get ~2000 quotes worth of requests.

Comment: @geostocker: Can't see any obvious flaws. You just have to remember that network roundtrip takes time, as does the HTTP handshaking overhead on top of that. Doing all 2,000 requests in serial is going to take a while. Have you considered parallelising them? Is there a way you can query the remote server for all 2,000 quotes in a single request? Or at least in batches?

Comment: Well, the initial (historical) batch will probably take some time, but it will only be a one-off. Once I have the historical data I can focus on running a query every hour to get the current stockdata (yahoo finance query limit is 2000 / hour).
I've been looking at libcurl's multithreading potential, and I do believe I should be able to construct a working example of it with my params. 
Basically will have to get the tickers, put tickers in a container, get size to initilize threadsize and then iterate through the tickers to get data, and put data in a database.
Probably going to be hard. :p

Comment: @geostocker: That sounds a little overengineered. Why not five worker threads with a cURL loop in each?

Answer (score 2):

When you include a file, .cpp or .h, the contents of the file are simply copied into the including file in preparation for the compilation phase.

Preprocessor directives are basically text-based operations that should not affect the execution speed of the program.

As you have mentioned, separating code into implementation and interface files helps with code maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

The way you split/organize your code, does not affect the running time of your executable.